# My mouse and keyboard have no effect on Raspberry Pi 4b

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I bought an SD card from PiHut, I formatted it, I then installed raspbian, then I plugged it into raspberry pi 4b and plugged mouse and keyboard in, powered up monitor and pi, it gets to the starter page with a "next" button, but when I move my mouse, the cursor doesn't move, the lights on my mouse also don't power up. Can anyone help?

Keyboard - ADVENT K112,
Mouse - Logitech G502 Hero,
Both mouse and keyboard work perfectly on other computers.
both connected via USB, I tried on USB 2 and USB 3 but neither work

Power Supply - Official UK Raspberry Pi 4 Power Supply (5.1V 3A)

Comment: @joan ok done that, do you have any possible solutions?

Comment: I have no idea.  If it was a new Pi I'd start to think it might be faulty.

Comment: @joan i was thinking the same, should I try for a refund?

Comment: @TV47 why would you ask that? ... the decision is entirely yours

Comment: @jsotola the RPi team have terrible customer service, i tried to ask them questions before but no one responded to my contact form

Comment: Try with different USB peripherals. If those work then it most likely isn't a hardware issue. Some HID devices may not work with generic drivers.

Comment: @TV47 I think warranty replacement is done through the distributor.  If possible, you should ssh in from another computer and see if  you can get the output from `dmesg` immediately after you plug the keyboard or mouse in (do it before as well to see if there is anything actually new; there should be regardless of whether the devices work).  I do not think those require any special driver for basic operation.  Also, if you can `sudo apt install usbutils` (will require internet) then get the output from `lsusb` with them plugged in.